# Monte Carlo - Random Walk Simulation - polyfit the log log data points?

Tags: matlab, monte-carlo, plotting, random-sampling, information-theory

This is part of the code in matlab for a random-walk simulation.

- To test the code, I'm using steps=[30]; there will be more values, but I want to run it for 1 trial to decrease code processing.
- `log_steps = log(1:steps);` <--- corresponds to the log (steps vector) for the x axis of the plot
- `log_AVG = log(d_AVG);` <---- corresponds to the log (average steps sizes) for the y axis of the plot

**The intended approach**
[image: d~sqrt(N) to find model's p value]

**to prove that $p$ which represents the probability of any step (forward || backward) is 0.5**.

PROBLEM: the program's p value estimation is 10x larger than it should be. It gives a value between 4 to 5 for p, when p should be about 0.5.

**where is the logic wrong? Relevant code below.**

```
    figure(i+10);
    hold on;
    loglog(log_steps, log_AVG,'-s');
    %loglog(1:steps(i), d_AVG, '-s');

    N=log_steps;
    c= log_AVG;



    p = polyfit(N, c,0);
    f = (c.* (N.^p));
    hold on;
    loglog(N, f);
    hold off;
    end;
```

[image: "hyperbolic curve" <--- log-log plot of 30 step random walk without polyfit attempt]

[image: "straight horizontal line" <-- log-log plot of ONLY randomwalk points]

Comment: What language is this? Can you reformat your question so the code displays nicely and the images show?

Answer (score 1):

If I understood the first image correctly, you should do a linear fit with $\ln(N)$ being the independent variable and, presumably, $\ln(d)$ the dependent variable.

Furthermore, it seems to me that in your code you use $c$ as $\log(d_{AVG})$, which is different from the first image, where $c$ appears to be a constant.

(I'm not giving a full answer because it seems to me that it's a homework question.)